# android surprising difference between Date and GregorianCalendar - bug?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
public static final long ONE_DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS = 24*60*60*1000;
(...)
Date newNextTestDate = new Date ( (new Date().getTime()) + newInterval*ONE_DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS);
System.out.println("data: " +newNextTestDate.getTime());

GregorianCalendar tmp2Date = new GregorianCalendar ();
tmp2Date.add(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, newInterval);
System.out.println(" data2: " +tmp2Date.getTimeInMillis());

//where newInterval is number of days (int)
```

In Android 4.0.4 and 4.2.2 in 2/3 of cases the displayed values are the same (sometimes minor difference). However in 1/3 of cases there is the difference of.... 3600000 (or something similar like 3600001) which is the equivalent of one hour. Moreover if I have this in a loop, it seems to be fully random, on the same device, without touching any system settings, sometimes that difference exist and sometimes not. Is there any bug in Android implementation of Date?

Comment: Could this be occurring when your interval spans the beginning or the end of  daylight savings time?

Comment: OK, so what's the value of `newInterval` that gives you this problem?  And what timezone are you in?  Give me something to try out and debug.  Because honestly, apart from the daylight savings issue, your code looks OK to me.  Incidentally, you'll definitely get this bug occurring when daylight savings begins or ends, so you may want to sort that out.

Comment: newInterval is the number of days, any value from 1 to very high values ex. 2000. Time zone is set automatically by network (and currently it's GMT +02.00. And the bugs happened many times even today, and the nearest daylight savings change is late autumn.

Comment: Please tell me a specific value for `newInterval` for which it happens, so I can try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I didn't notice any specific value, usually newInterval is the value between 1 to 1000. Please look also on my answer, which suggest that there is important difference between Date and GregorianCalendar implementation.

Comment: OK, if you're happy, I won't argue.  But they're actually the same under the hood.

Comment: What it can be important also, the sdk I use - android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="14"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the reason of problems, but I've found the workaround.

When instead of using `new Date()` I use `(new GregorianCalendar()).getTime` this strange "effect" doesn't appear.